# Altering table cell header on action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a header in my sectioned table view that contains a button that expands its cells when tapped, I have a right ward facing arrow in the header as well, and when the header is tapped I want to change that arrow image to a downward facing arrow, how can I alter the section's header? Specifically the `arrowButton`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width - 30, height: 50))
        button.setTitle(tableDataSource[section][0].mod.modType!, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica neue", size: 20)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(headerPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
        
        button.tag = section
        
        let arrowButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        arrowButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right", compatibleWith: nil), for: .normal)
        header.addSubview(arrowButton)
        
        header.addSubview(button)
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        
        
        
        return header
    }

@objc func headerPressed(sender: UIButton){
        if(tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked == false){
            tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked = true
        } else {
            tableDataSource[sender.tag][0].clicked = false
        }
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: sender.tag)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this inside `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
let name = tableDataSource[section][0].clicked ? "chevron.right" : "chevron.left"
arrowButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName:name, compatibleWith: nil), for: .normal)
```

And calling this  `tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)` will do the reload job

Comment: That worked, I was trying to do it in the ```headerPressed``` function, thank you!